# PHP Paypal IPN Get transcation array

Tags: php, paypal

How do I get transaction array within $_POST array?

Response:

```
cmd=_notify-validate&transaction=Array
```

Thats the response I get from my ipn ( minus all the other good stuff after transaction array )

I need to get the transaction amount, currency, and receiver which is.

```
transaction[n].receiver
transaction[n].amount
transaction[n].currency
```

I have tired `$_POST['transaction']['amount']`and it doesn't work since their numbers between `$_POST['transaction'][n]['amount']`

Comment: are you using one of the provided php scripts from paypal?

Comment: you need to clarify what that Response is. Where did you get it from? And does it say "Array" literally or is there actually the values you are looking for in that Response body? If it says Array, the IPN is bugged and string converted a real array, which means its doesnt contain the values you want. What does `var_dump($_POST['transaction'])` give?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was to use [Daniel De Sousa's solution](http://enjoysmile.com/blog/24/paypal-adaptive-payments-and-ipn-part-two/).  The solution works well, but I'm concerned Paypal will change some small variable at some point and break the implementation.  Overall, the Paypal support and documentation for adaptive payments IPN responses is subpar.

Comment: Hi guys. Just letting you know my solution (actually [donut2d's](https://www.x.com/users/donut2d)) is still functioning well. What I try to do in my code samples is keep the IPN message and data processing separate since PayPal sends variables in a slightly strange format. Hope it helps!